# Angular 7 routing ignore path

Tags: angular7-router

I have an Angular 7 application, running .Net Core on the back end.
I have the following routes defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' } 
];
```

In Visual Studio 2019, this is running at https://localhost:44358.

All works as expected.

But now I want to get metadata for a SAML implementation using sustainsys.saml2.aspnetcore2.
To get the metadata file, I try to enter https://localhost:44358/Saml2/ in my browser.
As expected, because  the path does not match anything defined, the default route takes over and I am routed to the home page.

I removed the final path, so I no longer had any default routing for unmatched paths, and then it worked fine to get the metadata.

My question is: Is there any way to redirect to 'home' for all unmatched paths *except* some configured path (or paths), which would just be ignored as if the default route were not present?

Answer (score 0):

Rather add a path to your [base-href](https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href-1) in index.html (e.g. `<base href="/app/"/>`) so that the Angular Router won't pick up paths on your root, then you'll be able to keep your wildcard redirect as is and `/Saml2/` won't be intercepted.

Of course, if the app is already in production and you need to preserve URLs, you might not be in a position to make this kind of change.